# magento 2 category and product page displaying blank

Tags: php, magento2

I have upgraded magento from 2.1.10 to 2.2.5. First I have upgraded it local and all things are working in local then I have upload those source code in beta and did following process :

1. php bin/magento s:up
2. php bin/magento s:s:d
3. php bin/magento c:c
4. php bin/magento c:f
5. php bin/magento i:rei

In beta database was of magento 2.1.1 but after did above process now my magento is 2.2.5.

All things are working but the Category and Product detail page is not opening. It is displaying blank a white page.

I checked error in var/log but no error. I have enabled the error in index.php but with no luck.

I gave permission to var and generate obv.

I changed theme to default theme and also tried by disable all extension.

Please share an idea or suggestion to help me.

Comment: have you already set developer mode and then enabled the errors?

Comment: Yes the mode is developer and enable error

Comment: probably the problem is **local.xml** file.. well, if the filename is **local.xml.sample** in pub/errors folder then change it to pub/errors/local.xml

Comment: Yes I just did this but same result still blank page.

Comment: after renaming **local.xml** remove `var/di var/cache var/composer_home var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed var/generation` folders and also remove `pub/static` (except `.htaccess` file) and then static content deploy and at after that try to remove the browser cache as well.. Reload the page again... and it's better to check indexer status.. are they full reindexed or not...

Comment: yes indexer is full reindexed

Comment: I checked by rm -rf var/* and generated/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and want to share with you so It can be helpfull for other...

Actully I am using porto theme and the issue is in placeholder image. The name of the images are different then database.

I re-upload the images and it is working now. But I can not understand why its totally stop the catalog and product page to be run. It should display the error. Anyway it is working now.

Thanks for help.